# jQuery many to many relation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm making a picture competition page (with different rules)

I can't seem to wrap my head around this 'problem'

The rule is: A user can vote for ONE picture, but not his own.
and he is able to remove his vote, and vote for another.

I have PHP to check for all that, and it works fine.

The type is 0 is this case

```
function addVote(pictureID, competitionID, type){
$.post('vote.php', {pictureID:pictureID, competitionID:competitionID, vote:1}, function(data){
    if (data == 'success') {
    $("#comp_voteButton_"+pictureID).text('Remove vote');
    $("#comp_voteButton_"+pictureID).addClass("alreadyVoted");
    $("#comp_voteButton_"+pictureID).attr("onclick", "remVote(" + pictureID + ", " + competitionID + ")")
    if (type == 0){
    $('.button:not(.disabled, #comp_voteButton_'+pictureID+')').text('Only one vote permitted');
    $('.button:not(.disabled, #comp_voteButton_'+pictureID+')').removeClass('alreadyVoted');
            $('.button:not(.disabled)').addClass('.disabled, .red');

    getVote(pictureID, competitionID);
    }else {
        $().toastmessage('showErrorToast', "Error!");
    }
});
```

}

In the same file:

```
function remVote(pictureID, competitionID){
$.post('vote.php', {pictureID:pictureID, competitionID:competitionID, vote:0}, function(data){
    if (data == 'success') {
    $("#comp_voteButton_"+pictureID).text('Vote picture');
    $("#comp_voteButton_"+pictureID).attr("onclick", "addVote(" + pictureID +","+competitionID+","+0+")")
    $("#comp_voteButton_"+pictureID).removeClass('alreadyVoted');
    getVote(pictureID, competitionID);
    }else {
        $().toastmessage('showErrorToast', "Error!");
    }
});
```

}

edit:
Here's the link if that makes it easier:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="button blue small" id="comp_voteButton_<?echo $row['ID']?>" onclick="addVote(<?echo $row['ID']?>, <?echo $id?>, <?echo $vote?>)">Vote</a>
```

What I want: On addVote all the other buttons should be set to 'onclick(remVote(ID, compID))' - But I can't do that because both the ID's are not fed into the addVote function.

I hope you guys get my question (maybe it isn't possible, or a weird work-around has to be made) - But maybe there's a nifty way of doing it.

Comment: So is the problem that you want to set all of the pictures' onclicks to remove the currently selected vote?

Comment: Yes (which is simple enough) - but the toughest part is, when the user then clicks the button (on another picture, it should vote for the picture, and remove the old one)..

Answer (score 0):

Okay I admit it's a darn weird problem.

But I did something else instead (and thanks for your time)

What I did instead: in addVote...

```
$('.button:not(.disabled, #comp_voteButton_'+pictureID+')').hide();
```

It then hides all other buttons, so the user won't think they can vote for more than one picture. and on the removeVote part then shows all buttons again.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be easier if you had the picture's ID in a data-value attribute or something, but you could do something like this inside of the addVote function.

```
$("[id*=comp_voteButton]").each(function (i) {
    $(this).click(function(){
        remVote(pictureID, competitionID);
        var id = this.id.substring(16);
        addVote(id, competitionID);
    }
}
```